# REST Аутентификация пользователя по apiKey

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Как организовать аутентификацию пользователя по его `apiKey` ?
Пробовал вот так, но проблема в том, что `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` ожидает пароль в чистом виде, а в БД он зашифрован.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/v1")
public class ApiV1 {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository; 

    @PostMapping("authorize")
    ResponseEntity<ApiError> authorize(@RequestHeader(value = "apiKey") String apiKey) {
        UserDetails user = userRepository.findByApiKey(apiKey);
        if (user == null) 
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ApiError("API KEY NOT FOUND"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

        try {
            Authentication authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null) ; 
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ApiError("UNAUTHORIZED", e.toString()), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ApiError("OK"), HttpStatus.OK);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому пригодиться

```
public void authWithoutPassword(User user){
    List<Privilege> privileges = user.getRoles().stream()
      .map(role -> role.getPrivileges())
      .flatMap(list -> list.stream())
      .distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = privileges.stream()
        .map(p -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(p.getName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, authorities);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
}
```